# Rails: Calculate how many days are overlapped between 2 date ranges

Tags: ruby-on-rails

okay, lets say we have three date ranges.

```
1. date1=01-20-2015..02-15-2015
2. date2 = 01-01-2015..01-31-2015
3. date3 = 02-01-2015..02-28-2015
```

I need a way to calculate how many days between date1 and date2 are overlapped (10 days in this case). 
and how many days between date1 and date3 are overlapped (15 days in this case)?

Is there a easy way to calculate this?

Comment: There is a gem called 'validates_overlap'. I think https://github.com/robinbortlik/validates_overlap should be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you have:

```
r1= (Date.new(2015, 01, 20))..(Date.new(2015, 2, 15))
r2= (Date.new(2015, 01, 1))..(Date.new(2015, 1, 31))
```

You can check the intersection this way:

```
r1.to_a & r2.to_a
=> [Tue, 20 Jan 2015,
 Wed, 21 Jan 2015,
 Thu, 22 Jan 2015,
 Fri, 23 Jan 2015,
 Sat, 24 Jan 2015,
 Sun, 25 Jan 2015,
 Mon, 26 Jan 2015,
 Tue, 27 Jan 2015,
 Wed, 28 Jan 2015,
 Thu, 29 Jan 2015,
 Fri, 30 Jan 2015,
 Sat, 31 Jan 2015]
```

The cost is to convert ranges to arrays though

You can notice `(r1.to_a & r2.to_a).count #=> 12`, not `10` but well depends whether or not you include boundaries.

Comment: thank you very much, this is indeed a creative way to solve this issue.